# how to dynamically show content of view

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP when i work with views in MySQL. I want to dynamically show in HTML content of this view (columns and data). So I want to show data based on view. It must to find out count of columns in view and data. How to show it in HTML using PHP?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Have you tried searching for a solution? I would suggest a beginners book or online tutorial to get you started eg http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql Then if you have problems return here with your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

just to give you an idea, but anyway, i suggest you to look for a tutorial and learn PHP .

```
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php
    try{
          $con=new PDO("mysql::host=localhost;dbname=databasename;","username","password");
          $query="SELECT * FROM tablename ";
          $res=$con->query($query);
          $rows=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
          foreach($rows as $row)
          {
             echo $row["0"]."--".$row["1"]."--".$row["2"]."--".$row["3"]."--".$row["5"].<br>;//depends on how many columns you get in the query result
          }      
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        die("error:".$e->getMessage() );
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```